# Attaching event to document, that depends on conditionally rendered element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, ecmascript-6

I have an input element, that is rendered depending on condition.

```
render() {
const {
  isNameInputVisible,
  name
} = this.state;

return (

    <div>
      {isNameInputVisible ? (
        <input
          onChange={this.handleNameChange}
          ref={this.nameInput}
          type="text"
          value={name}
        />
      ) : (
        <h1
          className="list-header__heading"
          onClick={this.handleNameInputVisibility}
        >
          {name}
        </h1>
      )}
    </div>
)
```

**Basically, I want to listen for a click on the document, to hide the input whenever user click's outside this input element.**

Right now I'm doing this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
  }


  handleClick = event => {
      //do some logic
  };
```

But I've been wondering if this is the correct way, because the event exists and fires, 
even when the element is not rendered.

So I've tried this:

```
componentDidUpdate () {
   const {isNameInputVisible} = this.state;
    isNameInputVisible &&  document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**Question 1:** 
What is the right way of attaching events to document when it depends on other conditionally rendered elements??

**Question 2:**
What is the correct way of attaching events, for example, like escape press, for closing dialogs that o etc??

Comment: Add listener in componentDidmount. Check `target` in handler. Make sure to remove listener in `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: this is how I'm doing this right now :) 
But the handler fires even when I don't need it, cause Input is not visible.

So that's why I wonder if this is the correct way?

Comment: Could make the input a component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event listener in the `componentDidMount` method only if the conditionally rendered element's ref exists. You can tell if a ref has been attached to an element by using `this.refName.current`.

The most important thing here is that the `input` element gets its own lifecycle methods instead of sharing them with a larger component. By moving the `input` element to its own component with its own lifecycle methods, those methods will only fire around the creation and removal of the `input`.

```
// App.jsx
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

import CustomInput from "./CustomInput"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = React.createRef()
    this.toggleInput = this.toggleInput.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      inputVisible: false
    }
  }

  toggleInput(e) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      inputVisible: !prevState.inputVisible
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { inputVisible } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="toggle input" onClick={this.toggleInput} />
        { inputVisible
          ? <CustomInput />
          : <p>Input is not visible</p>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

```
// CustomInput.jsx
import React from "react"

export default class CustomInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.inputRef.current &&
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClick)
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    console.log("clicked")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" ref={this.inputRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

## [Try it here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/l5rk62ynrz)

Comment: This will not work. as by deafult. Input is invisible, so react will not create a ref to it.
I've tried the same appraoch in componentDidMount(). 

Like this: 
componentDidMount() {
   this.inputRef.current && document.addEventListener().....
}

but in this approach, even when the state was updated to isInputVisible to true - the eventListener was not attached to document.

Comment: This is because the ref needs to be attached to a conditional element using the component's lifecycle methods that are called after the input is created. Once you move the input element to its own component with its own lifecycle methods, it works perfectly. I'll update my answer with this.